# How to add a button to Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to add a simple button to the Firefox interface:  The button will bookmark the current page under the most recently used bookmark folder.

Could you please guide me in the general direction?  I am a programmer, but have no Firefox programming experience.

(PS: Is this considered an add-on?)

Thanks -

Todd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, if you want to add a toolbar button, then you can do it as an addon.

I suggest to start reading the [*XUL School*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School), which should give a good introduction into Firefox addon development.

For learning how to access and manage bookmarks, read about [*Places*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Places).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the links.